Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool
Problem:
I'm working on a dependency migration task trying to migrate the Spring codebase from Spring 2.6.9 to Spring 2.7.0. However, am facing some issues related to the migration H2.
I read the migration guide of the Spring 2.7 which states

Spring Boot 2.7 has upgraded to H2 2.1.120. H2 2.x is backwards incompatible and fixes a number of security vulnerabilities. See the H2 changelog and migration guide for details of the changes and how to handle the upgrade.

application.properties
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create

DataSource.java

@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(datasource());
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(properties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    JdbcConnectionPool datasource() {
        return JdbcConnectionPool.create("jdbc:h2:mem:testdb", "user", "password");
    }
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager
                = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    Properties properties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        return properties;
    }

}

POM.xml
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </parent>

..

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
                <version>9.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

Stacktrace
When running my application I find below useful stack trace logs:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource 
[DataSourceConfig.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: 

Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool: 
Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPoo


Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: 
Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool: 
Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool
...


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:660) ~[spring-core-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]

What didn't work!
I've read below questions/answers:

Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class - Common causes ... final class

Spring AspectJ fails when double-proxying interface: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class

After spring upgrade: could not generate CGLIB subclass of class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy


However, didn't find anything useful.
I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

JdbcConnectionPool is a final class and cannot be proxied. But why have you defined this in the first place? Just remove that @Bean method and Spring will create a DataSource for you based on the properties (basically your application.properties shown is useless as those aren't used).

Hi @M.Deinum you are absolutely right. I didn't want to create the Datasource bean as Spring creates one, however I wanted a sessionFactory bean I didn't find any way of creating a sessionFactory without using Datasource. So mistakenly have created one, while I could have injected one. Thanks for spotting that.

As commented by @M. Deinum

Spring will create a DataSource for you based on the properties

We don't need to create a datasource explicitly, and as far as sessionFactory is concerned. We can create one using LocalSessionFactoryBean as below:
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import javax.sql.DataSource

@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        final var sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);

        return sessionFactory;
    }
}


You don't need the @Autowired. Don't call afterPropertiesSet() and remove the @SneakyThrows. IN fact you could ditch the whole class. Spring Boot already configures JPA and the Hibernate EntityManagerFactory is actually a SessionFactory as well. So you don't need any of this and can just use Spring Boot autoconfiguration for all.

@M.Deinum I've updated my answer above.

@M.Deinum when removing the explicit sessionFactory bean I get compilation error No bean named 'sessionFactory' available error. Seems EntityManagerFactory is not getting created.

It is created but you are injecting it somewhere by name instead of by type.
